# How to trigger the API with Modal in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I need help to know how to trigger a delete API after a modal confirmation in Angular.

```
onDelete(id: number) {
    
    this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Confirm Delete', 'Do you really want to delete this document?')
    .then(() => this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)) //this is not working
    //.catch(() => console.log('User dismissed the dialog (e.g., by using ESC, clicking the cross icon, or clicking outside the dialog)'));

    /*if (confirm('Are you sure you want delete this record?') == true) {
      this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
    }*/
  }
```

As you can see in the code. I need to know how I make the call to the delete API after clicking the OK button in the modal.

Comment: can you show `confirmationDialogService.confirm` code?

Comment: I based it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-confirmation-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bracket `{}` within `.then` to use multiline code, like below -

```
public openConfirmationDialog(id) {
    this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Please confirm..', 'Do you really want to ... ?')
    .then((confirmed) => {
      this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
      console.log('User confirmed:', confirmed);
    })
    .catch(() => console.log('User dismissed the dialog (e.g., by using ESC, clicking the cross icon, or clicking outside the dialog)'));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Pardeep! Its now working! I've also added the working code.

Answer (score 0):

onDelete(id: number) {

```
this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Confirm Delete', 'Do you really want to delete this document?')
  .then((confirmed) => {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)
    .subscribe(x => {
      this.employeeService.getEmployeeList();
      this.toast.warning("Deleted Sucessfully", 'Employee Register');
    });
  })
```

}